# Press back button to another activity

Tags: java, android

I try the code below to call another activity while pressing the back button:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg) {
   switch(keyCode) {
       case(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK):
       Intent intent = new Intent(AActivity.this, BActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  
       Window w = NASGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("BActivity", intent);  
       View view = w.getDecorView();  
       MyGroup.group.setContentView(view);  
       return true; 
   }
   return false;
}
```

But when I press the back button, it get out of the app.
I see the logcat, it does not run the function `onKeyUp` and doesn't output any message.
The same code in `onKeyUp`, I try to below code to a button in layout and it works.

```
cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(AActivity.this, BActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  
      Window w = NASGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("BActivity", intent);  
      View view = w.getDecorView();  
      MyGroup.group.setContentView(view);  
   }
});
```

How can I modify it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To handle back press you have to override Onbackpress method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    finish();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Myactivity.this, other.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try overriding the activity's onBackPressed() method

from the docs : [onBackPressed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

Try like this...

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent BackpressedIntent = new Intent();
    BackpressedIntent .setClass(getApplicationContext(),TargetActivity.class);
    BackpressedIntent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(BackpressedIntent );
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For back button you have to override the OnBackPressed() in your activity as

```
   @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent=new Intent(currentclass.this,nextActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();


}
```

if you didnt finish the previous activity then no need to use intent and startActivity just call  finish(); in the onBackPressed it will finish the current activity and previous activity will started.

Comment: please dont repeat the answers if your answers seem similar to the previous

Answer (score 1):

If you are within **Activity** you can use **onBackPressed** which is a built-in method to handle back key press.